# Any call from inside a iframe note fetch by Service worker - CK Editor

Tags: iframe, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, ckeditor4.x

Service worker to make the application offline, in my application there is on iframe which src is empty and inside the iframe am injecting few css file. These GET to get the CSS are not hitting the fetch call of the Service worker.

> Mainly i am facing this issue when am using CK editor, They have
>   implemented the iframe and all the plugin CSS getting rendered inside
>   the Iframe those CSS are not getting cached in CACHE API. so when went offline the CK editor is not working properly

After few reading this is because the scope issue of the service worker i tried few way to do this. found below code

```
 <iframe id="sampleIframe" src="./iframe" style="width:300px;height:400px;float: left;"> </iframe>
```

on page load

```
var link= '<link href="./sample.css" rel="stylesheet" /><h1>Hi</h1>'; 
        var ifrm = document.getElementById('sampleIframe');
        ifrm = (ifrm.contentWindow) ? ifrm.contentWindow : (ifrm.contentDocument.document) ? ifrm.contentDocument.document : ifrm.contentDocument;
        ifrm.document.open();
        ifrm.document.write(link);
        ifrm.document.close();
```

Everything is working fine but the CSS is not getting cached into Cache API . 
** this is pseudo code

Answer (score 2):

The `document.open()` creates an "about:blank" document.  The spec requires inheriting the parent document's controller, but currently chrome does not implement this feature.  See:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=880768

Comment: Is there any way i can make the scope of parent service worker inside Iframe also. any hack ? am realy stuck here

Comment: Instead of document.open()/write() you could maybe use document.createElement() to create the link and then insert it into the frame's body.